# PySVN error: URL doesn't exist

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

I got a SVN repository copied onto my computer using svnsync. Now when I try to replay it using PySVN it fails at a specific revision (29762) with the message:

> pysvn._pysvn_2_6.ClientError: URL 'svn://svn.zope.org/repos/main/ZODB/trunk/src/Persistence' doesn't exist

I can checkout or update until the previous revision (29761) ok but after that I get this error.

My objective is to analyze the code structure and it's evolution so I have

```
client.update(path,
revision=pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number,
RevNumber),ignore_externals=False)
```

within a `for` loop that increments `RevNumber`

I am ok with ignoring this specific revision, so if there is a way around it that will allow my checked-out code to progress and be analyzed, that will be fine (as long as there aren't many more instances of this happening).

Nevertheless, if my repo is a copy of a working repo, why doesn't it work and how does the original one function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the error message doesn't hint to that, I believe it was caused by running out of disk space. After deleting other files on the drive and re-running the script it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    client.update(path,revision=pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number,RevNumber),ignore_externals=False)
except: 
    print "Revision skipped at", RevNumber
    continue
```

This does not solve the problem, but you can use try/ except for your code to go on, if you are ok with omitting some revisions, like you've said.

Comment: `except:` is never the right thing to catch. It hides coding error and unexpected problems.